# Fabric JS: How to shift inverse scaled group relative to background image on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I'm working on a project where a group is being scaled inversely on zoom event. I figured out how to reposition the group to keep the position of it relative to the background image while zooming. My problem is that after zooming, the group's objects were resized as expected, but thanks to that, the triangle bottom apex (look at the fiddle example, it will make sense) is now shifted from its original position.

Here is a demo for the zooming: https://jsfiddle.net/Xyzor/3mh6g3jg

The zoom function which calculates the group's offset

```
function zoom(factor) {
  var beforeW = 0,
    beforeH = 0;
  factor += c.getZoom();

  c.setZoom(factor)
    .setWidth(500 * factor)
    .setHeight(500 * factor);

  c.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    beforeW = obj.getWidth();
    beforeH = obj.getHeight();

    obj.setScaleX(1 / factor)
      .setScaleY(1 / factor)
      .setLeft(obj.getLeft() + beforeW - obj.getWidth())
      .setTop(obj.getTop() + beforeH - obj.getHeight())
      .setCoords();
  });
  c.renderAll();
}
```

What I tried is that I calculated the distance between the triangle bottom apex and the right side of the group's bounding rectangle before zoom. I did this after zoom too and shifted the group with the difference of this two value. I calculated the vertical offset the same way (with the bottom of the bounding rectangle), but it didn't work (this is just the zoom in offset). I'm not sure if i used the right coordinates of the triangle object.

**Expected result:**
After zooming, the bottom apex of the triangle keeps its position relative to the background image (in the example above it means, stays on the origo).

**Current result:**
After zooming, thanks to the scaling, the bottom apex of the triangle is pointing to a different position on the background image.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution:

Set the origin of your group like this:

```
var group = new fabric.Group(
  [circle, triangle, text], {
    left: left,
    top: top,
    type: 'group',
    hasControls: false,
    hasBorders: true,
    borderColor: 'blue',
    originX:'center',
    originY:'bottom'
};
```

Then simply scale the the group in the zoom function like this:

```
var groupScale = 1/factor;
group.setScaleX(groupScale).setScaleY(groupScale);

c.renderAll();
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/3mh6g3jg/9/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it looks like I wasn't clear in my explanation. In the fiddle it's just an example, the group can be positioned anywhere on the canvas.

Comment: Right, and I wasn't also clear in my explanation :-). See my updated answer, you can position in anywhere. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your solution (see here: https://jsfiddle.net/Xyzor/3mh6g3jg/6/). For the sake of simplicity I set the group's original positions to `originalPositionX = canvasWidth / 2 - groupWidth/2` and `originalPositionY = canvasHeight / 2 - groupHeight`. Even like this the group's position still bad after zooming.

Also my main problem is to determine the `(originalPositionX,originalPositionY)` position of the tip of triangle wherever is it on the canvas.

Comment: Right, sorry, I had a bug in my fiddle. Looks like you need to apply the scale first and then get the correct group width and height. I updated the fiddle, seems to be working correctly now.

Comment: Also, no need to call setCoords() when using setters like setLeft() etc.

Comment: It seems to be working but there is a tiny bug and i couldn't find what is causing it.
If I change the group's position from the center of the canvas, at the first zoom the group shifts more than it should be. I checked the `(x,y)` values before and after the scaling and it seems to be ok. After the first zoom call, it's working ok.

Comment: Hey, I just found the most simple solution which solved the problem with shifting. See my updated answer.

Comment: Your final solution worked for me perfectly. Thank your for your help.